# Static file (images & CSS for admin) is not loading

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

On my Django website When I am making `DEBUG = True` Images are not loading.
Please find my Dir structure and code.

**Settings.py**

```
    STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
    
STATIC_URL = '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    STATIC_DIR,
]

MEDIA_URL = "/abcd/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ------
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    -- - - - - -
]
```

**Models.py**

```
  class Product(models.Model):
    " " " 
     - -- - - -- - - 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/products/', default='',null=True, blank=True)
    """""""""
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/products/')
```

**urls.py**
from django.conf.urls.static import static

```
urlpatterns = [
    """"""",
   
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

HTML file:

```html
  {% if product.image %}

                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt=".." height="45px" width="45px">
                        {% endif %}
```

here If I am changing Debug=False It is working as expected but when it is True images are not loading and in admin page CSS is not working.

Can anyone help me with steps on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: the issue has been resolved after referring the below document.
- https://overiq.com/django-1-10/handling-media-files-in-django/#:~:text=The%20problem%20is%20that%20Django,in%20sitewide%20urls.py%20file.&text=Now%20visit%20http%3A%2F%2F127.0,able%20to%20see%20the%20image.

Comment: [You can find here another way to solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129007/django-static-css-is-not-loading-on-page)

Comment: [To resolve your problem you can try:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129007/django-static-css-is-not-loading-on-page)