# Django static css is not loading on page

Tags: python, html, css, django

I know there are many posts about this, but I have been unable to resolve my problem (for example following this: [Django static files (css) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895497/django-static-files-css-not-working)). I can't get my css static file to load on this practice page, css_practice.html.

I have the following structure

```
djangoAjax
 settings.py
 ...
 djangoAjaxApp
   static
     ok.css
   templates
     css_practice.html
```

My settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = '############################################'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "crispy_forms",
    'djangoAjaxApp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoAjax.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoAjax.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), BASE_DIR / "static",
]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
{% comment %} https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=django+static+css&docid=608004894969656896&mid=E118E7C4ADFE161B3B12E118E7C4ADFE161B3B12&view=detail&FORM=VIRE {% endcomment %}
    {% load static %}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href"{% static 'djangoAjaxApp\static\ok.css' %}">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="ok">My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
# css practice
def cssRender(request):
     return render(request, "css_practice.html")
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import cssRender

urlpatterns = [
    path('css/', cssRender, name='cssRender'),
]
```

I imagine I might be messing up the folder structure somehow... there is also a reference in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

about adding

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

But since I am using, `django.contrib.staticfiles`  in settings, I'm assuming this is done automatically.

Currently the page loads, but css is not applied.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**settting.py:**

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Only one `{% load static %}` is enough in your html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
```

You have to Copy and Plast your STATIC files (Js, CSS, ...) in your templates.

It will look like that :

```html
djangoAjaxApp
|_migrations
|_templates
|     |_djangoAjaxApp
|           |_css_practice.html
|_static
    |___djangoAjaxApp (directory with the same App name)
         |_(here all your static file)
```

**Your HTML will look like this:**

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href"{% static 'djangoAjaxApp\ok.css' %}">
```

**views.py:**

```
# css practice

def cssRender(request):

    return render(request, "djangoAjaxApp/css_practice.html")
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cssRender, name='cssRender'),
        ]
```

**djangoAjax urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try it.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment @Sevdimali. That did not change anything. not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Just to remind you of it, have you tried hard refresh on your browser? I used to miss this when I was a beginner. (You can do it in chrome with ctrl+shift+r).